# PHP remove items from recursive array if id don't match

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling to remove item from recursive array if parent id don't match. All I want to display separate tree for each tree number. I didn't find any solution with SQL so now I am retrieving top nodes of that tree number and removing array those items don't have that top node ids. I already have tree structure, below I'm providing the structure of array.

```
{
  "196": {
    "id": "196",
    "username": "test1",
    "parent_id": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "197",
        "parent_id": "196",
        "flower_id": null,
        "username": "test1",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "id": "198",
        "parent_id": "196",
        "flower_id": "1690587",
        "username": "test3",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "213",
            "parent_id": "198",
            "flower_id": "5197062",
            "username": "test33",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "199",
        "parent_id": "196",
        "flower_id": "1690587",
        "username": "test2",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "205",
            "parent_id": "199",
            "flower_id": null,
            "username": null,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "207",
                "parent_id": "205",
                "flower_id": null,
                "username": null,
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "212",
            "parent_id": "199",
            "flower_id": "6794158",
            "username": "gunu",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is what I'm doing doing

```
function recursive_unset(&$array, $parentIds = array()) {
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {
      if(!in_array($value['parent_id'], $parentIds)) {
        unset($array[$key]);
      }
      if (is_array($value['children'])) {
          $this->recursive_unset($value, $parentIds);
      }
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling this function `$data = $this->recursive_unset($array, [198,199]);`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more clear what does it mean by "if parent id don't match"? Say which should be removed in your example?

Comment: @KoalaYeung, thanks alot for your reply. I want to remove all items where parent_id is not 198 or 199.